# What is the limit of $\log_k(k^a + k^b)$ for $k \to +\infty$?

Tags: limits, logarithms, exponentiation, proof-explanation

I'm not very good with analysis (I never studied it) but because of my "work" on other topics of mathematics I came to this problem.

$$\lim_{k \to +\infty }\log_k(k^a + k^b)=\max(a,b)$$

I'm sure that this is really "reasonable" because I tryed to graph it for really huge values of $k$ ... but "reasonable" is not enough in mathematics: I'd like to prve this.
 So I'm courious to know how one should go to prove it in a formal way ... if it is true (I hope).

PS: I know nothing about Limits and their rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss if generality assume $a\ge b$ then:

$$\log_{k}(k^{a}+k^{b})=a+\log_{k}(1+k^{b-a})=a+\frac{\ln(1+k^{b-a})}{\ln(k)}$$

where I changed the base of the logarithm to get the second equality. Notice that if $a>b$ then $1+k^{b-a}\to1$ and $\ln(k)\to\infty$ both as $k$ tends to $\infty$. If $a=b$ then $1+k^{b-a}=2$ but $\ln(k)\to\infty$ as $k\to\infty$. Thus, the above tends to $a=\max\{a,b\}$.

Comment: Ah thanks! Is really easy in this way. Since the function $ln$ is increasing and goes to infinity and it is in the denominator of the fraction, the value of $ln(1+k^{b-a})/ln(k)$ goes to zero (because $ln(1+k^{b-a})$ tends to $1$ when $a-b$ is negative). OK thanks! It was easier than I've expected!

Comment: You're welcome! Although I should point out that for $a>b$ $\ln(1+k^{b-a})$ tends to $0$ not to $1$. Also if $a=b$ then it is always $\ln(2)$.

Comment: Yea sorry, my error. I meant that $1+k^{b-a}$ tends to 1, so $\ln(1+k^{b-a})$ tends to $\ln(1)=0$

Answer (score 6):

Use the functional equation:

$\log(k^a+k^b)=a+\log(1+k^{b-a})$

When $a> b$ the log term goes to $0$, if $b\ge a$ it goes to $b-a$ and $b-a+a=b$.

Answer (score 5):

Assume that $a\geqslant b$ then $k^a\leqslant k^a+k^b\leqslant 2k^a$ hence $a\leqslant\log _k(k^a+k^b)\leqslant a+\log_k2$ and $\log_k2=\frac{\log2}{\log k}$. Can you finish?

Comment: what happened??

Answer (score 3):

If $a\gt b$ then $$\log_k(k^a+k^b)=\log_k k^a+\log_k (1+k^{b-a})$$

(Note that if $a=b$ you get $a+\log_k(2)$)

Then the first term is constant and the limit of the second is easy to establish.

Comment: Mhh..for $a=b$ we have that $log_k(2)$ tends to $0$ when $k$ goes at infty right? So the limit still holds right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @MphLee If $a=b$ you can't use that the exponent $b-a$ is negative - which is a very easy argument - it doesn't quite prove the whole thing. So I really wanted to point out the trap of thinking you've done it without finishing off. Did's answer, of course, avoids this very neatly. But it might not be the first thing you think of doing. And as Adam says, the limit still holds.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following. Notice that: $$\lim_{k \to + \infty} \log_k(k^a + k^b) = \lim_{k \to + \infty} \frac{\ln(k^a + k^b)}{\ln k}$$
If $0 < a,b < 1$, the limit is $0$. Suppose $a,b > 1$ and use L'Hospital's rule. We get: $$\lim_{k \to +\infty} \frac{\frac{k^a \ln k + k^b \ln k}{k^a + k^b}}{\frac{1}{k}} = \lim_{k \to +\infty} \ln k \frac{k^{a +1} + k^{b + 1}}{k^a + k^b} = \lim_{k \to + \infty} \ln k \frac{k^{a + 1 -b} + k}{k^{a - b} + 1} \\ = \lim_{k \to +\infty} k \ln k \frac{k^{a - b} + 1}{k^{a - b} + 1} = \lim_{k \to +\infty} k \ln k = + \infty$$