# How to prove $\displaystyle\;\lim_{h \to 0} \log_{h}(h^a + h^b) = \min(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I've encountered the claim$$\displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0} \log_{h}(h^a + h^b) = \min(a, b)$$ in literature on min-plus algebra and I'm wondering if someone can indicate how to manage a proof of this? I'm thinking that we want to, without loss of generality, assume $a \le b$ and show under this assumption that $\displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0} \log_{h}(h^a + h^b) = a$. At this point it is tempting to appeal to the continuity of logarithms and exponentials by taking the base-$h$ exponential of each side, but this is problematic as the base $h$ is the parameter we are taking the limit of. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/853638/42969

Comment: To avoid complex numbers you need $h>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by computing the one-sided limit as follows:

$\begin{align}
&\quad  \lim_{s \to^+ 0} \log_s(s^a + s^b) \\
&= \lim_{s \to^+ 0} \frac{\log(s^a + s^b)}{\log(s)} \\
&= \lim_{s \to^+ 0} \frac{\left(\frac{as^{a-1} + bs^{b-1}}{s^a + s^b}\right)}{ (1/s)} \quad \text{by L'Hospital's rule}\\
&= \lim_{s \to^+ 0} \frac{as^a + bs^b}{s^a + s^b} \\
&= a \lim_{s \to^+ 0} \frac{s^a}{s^a + s^b} + b \lim_{s \to^+ 0} \frac{s^b}{s^a + s^b} \\
&= a \lim_{s \to^+ 0} \frac{1}{1 + s^{b-a}} + b \lim_{s \to^+ 0} \frac{1}{1 + s^{a-b}}
\end{align}$

At this point we have three cases to consider: $a < b$, $a = b$, and $a > b$. In order to handle these cases, we will make use of the following observations:

$\begin{align}
    \lim_{s \to^{+} 0} 1/(1 + s^c) &= 0 \;\text{if}\; c < 0 \\
    \lim_{s \to^{+} 0} 1/(1 + s^c) &= 0.5 \;\text{if}\; c = 0 \\
    \lim_{s \to^{+} 0} 1/(1 + s^c) &= 1 \;\text{if}\; c > 0
\end{align}$

In the case $a < b$ then $b - a > 0$ and $a - b < 0$ so that we can apply the above observations to conclude

$\begin{align}
   &\quad a \lim_{s \to^+ 0} \frac{1}{1 + s^{b-a}} + b \lim_{s \to^+ 0} \frac{1}{1 + s^{a-b}} \\
   &= a \cdot 1 + b \cdot 0 \\
   &= \min(a, b).
\end{align}$

Without loss of generality this covers the case $a > b$ as well.

In the case $a = b$ then $b - a = 0$ and $a - b = 0$ so that we can apply the above observations to conclude

$\begin{align}
   &\quad a \lim_{s \to^+ 0} \frac{1}{1 + s^{b-a}} + b \lim_{s \to^+ 0} \frac{1}{1 + s^{a-b}} \\
   &= a \cdot \frac{1}{2} + b \cdot \frac{1}{2} \\
   &= a \cdot \frac{1}{2} + a \cdot \frac{1}{2} \\
   &= a = \min(a, b).
\end{align}$

In each case we see that

$\lim_{s \to^+ 0} \log_s(s^a + s^b) = \min(a, b)$

as was required. QED.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $a<b$.

Then $\log_h(h^a+h^b)$
$=\log_hh^a+\log_h(1+h^{b-a})=$
$a+\log_h e . \ln(1+h^{b-a})$
$=a+\frac{1}{\ln h} .\ln (1+h^{b-a})$
The last product goes to 0 as $h \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

[Posted as a Community Wiki answer, because it's too long for a
comment.]

Although this only makes for a longer proof, I think it's worth
pointing out that the proposition is a disguised expression of the
convergence of the $p$-norm to the $\infty$-norm of a vector
$x\in\mathbb{R}^n.$

(In this case, $n=2,$ but the proposition generalises to arbitrary $n.$)

By definition, $\|x\|_\infty=\max\{|x_k|:1\leqslant k\leqslant n\},$
and $\|x\|_p=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|x_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$ for all
$p\geqslant1.$
From $\|x\|_\infty\leqslant \|x\|_p\leqslant n^{1/p}\|x\|_\infty$
and $\lim_{p\to\infty}n^{1/p}=1$ we get
$\lim_{p\to\infty}\|x\|_p=\|x\|_\infty.$

Taking $p=-\log_eh,$ $x_1=e^{-a}$ and $x_2=e^{-b},$ we get
\begin{multline*}
\log_h(h^a+h^b) = -\frac1p\log_e(x_1^p+x_2^p) = -\log_e\|x\|_p \\
\to -\log_e\|x\|_\infty = -\log_e(\exp(-\min\{a,b\})) = \min\{a,b\}.
\end{multline*}

Comment: The generalisation, of course, is (using essentially the same proof)
$$
\lim_{h\to0+}\log_h(h^{a_1}+h^{a_2}+\cdots+h^{a_n}) =
\min\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\} \quad (a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}).
$$